# Sed is not taking my regex

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have the following `sed` command ( for replacing certain contents with space/nothing):

```
sed "s/.* \[test] \(h\[W/L]-.*\)//g" file.log
```

but this gives me error like:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown option to `s'
```

where I'm making the mistake?

```
2013-12-04 00:00:39,629 INFO  [test] (h[W/L]-75) <a>
adasdsdads
asdasdsddsaadsdasds
</a>


2013-12-04 00:00:39,629 INFO  [test] (h[W/L]-75) <a>

asdasdsasaasdas


a

asdas
</a>
```

The required op is:

```
<a>
adasdsdads
asdasdsddsaadsdasds
</a>


<a>

asdasdsasaasdas


a

asdas
</a>
```

Comment: could you provide an input along with expected output? Escape `[]` to match a literal `[`, `]` symbols. For capturing groups, it would be `\(...\)` . To match a literal `()` symbols, the pattern should be `()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` inside the regexp:

```
sed "s/.* \[test] \(h\[W\/L]-.*\)//g" file.log
```

Otherwise, it's treated as the end of the regexp. Another solution is to use a different delimiter, that isn't used in your pattern:

```
sed "s|.* \[test] \(h\[W/L]-.*\)/||g" file.log
```

And if you're trying to match literal parentheses, they don't need to be escaped in `sed`. It should be:

```
sed "s|.* \[test] (h\[W/L]-.*)||g" file.log
```

Comment: Thanks it works. The file content is: `2013-12-04 00:00:39,629 INFO  [test] (h[W/L]-75) <a>
adasdsdads
asdasdsddsaadsdasds
</a>


2013-12-04 00:00:39,629 INFO  [test] (h[W/L]-75) <a>

asdasdsasaasdas


a

asdas </a>
`  when I do `sed "s/.* \[test] \(h\[W\/L]-.*\)//g" file.log` nothing is getting replaced. Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: the capturing group is an error (looking the data sample) and to the opposite of `\[` to espaping `[`, `(` don't need to be escaped to be litteral so `\(...\)` in this case should be `(...)`. An alternative is to use other separator than `/` to avoid escaping this char; keeping the pattern closer to data structure

Answer (score 1):

You could try this sed command.

```
$ sed 's/.* \[test\] (h\[W\/L\]-.*) *//g' file
<a>
adasdsdads
asdasdsddsaadsdasds
</a>


<a>

asdasdsasaasdas


a

asdas
</a>
```

`<space>*` at the last helps to remove the spaces following the last `)` bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 sed "s/.* \[test] \(h\[W\/L]-.*\)//g" file.log
```

Comment: `\(...\)` called capturing group in Basic sed.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's#.* \[test] (h\[W/L]-.*)##' file.log
```

- other separator than default `/` in `s///`, here `#`
- unescape `()` for the litterla use (opposite behaviour than `[`)
- no use of `g` option, only 1 occurence per line